Null AccessToken returned from AuthenticationResult
Working on an ASP.NET application that authenticates the user, then redeems the authorization code to get the access token, and it's based on
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi. Following is somewhat simplified code snippet.
public static class ApplicationBuilder
{
    public static async Task<IConfidentialClientApplication> BuildConfidentialClientApplication()
    {
        var certificate = await GetCertificate();
        var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithCertificate(certificate)
            .WithAuthority(Authority)
            .WithRedirectUri(postLogoutRedirectUri)
            .Build();
        ...
        return app;
    }
...
}

// Startup.Auth.cs
...
Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
{
    AuthorizationCodeReceived = async context =>
    {
        var clientApp = await ApplicationBuilder.BuildConfidentialClientApplication();
        // Upon successful sign in, get & cache a token using MSAL.
        // Value of scopes depends on environment. It looks something like
        //"api://fake72e7-2fe9-4d6f-a97a-7b94009ebeef/AuthorizationScope" 
        var result = await clientApp.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopes, context.Code).WithSendX5C(true).ExecuteAsync();
        Trace.Assert(result.AccessToken != null); // assertion fails
        // Use the result.AccessToken to call API endpoint...
    ...

The problem is result.AccessToken is null in production environment (in pre-production it works correctly). There were some similar question and the "solution" was to use the correct scope value, which I've already checked. Below is the screenshot of how the permission is setup in production. Only obvious difference from the pre-prod is that ApiAccess and AuthorizationScope are "Not granted for Microsoft", but I don't know what that means. I've gone through double, tripple checking configuration values, and feel like running out of ideas, and I'm in need of help. What other possible things should I check for? How would you go about debugging something like this? (Permission values have been altered in the picture below)


Where have you defined your scopes and what do they look like?

The object returned from AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode will contain other properties that indicate error conditions - you should check those first. Also, please show us what your var result contains before your call to Trace.Assert(result.AccessToken != null).

Initially when I got the access token as NULL:

To resolve the error, pass scope as var scopes = new[] { "openid profile offline_access https://b2c.onmicrosoft.com/ClientID/read https://b2c.onmicrosoft.com/ClientID/write" };
I am able to generate access token successfully:
        private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification notification)
        {
            try
            {
                // Build the confidential client application
                IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClient = MsalAppBuilder.BuildConfidentialClientApplication();

                // Define the scopes
                var scopes = new[] { "openid profile offline_access https://infrab2c.onmicrosoft.com/ClientID/read https://infrab2c.onmicrosoft.com/ClientID/write" };
                
                // Acquire the token by authorization code
                var result = await confidentialClient.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopes, notification.Code).ExecuteAsync();

                // Output the access token
                Console.WriteLine(result.AccessToken);
                Console.WriteLine(result.IdToken);
            }


Decoded access token contains scopes:

Logged in to the application:

If still the issue persists, make sure to grant admin consent to the API permissions as it says Admin consent is required:

Reference:
openid connect - B2C authentication not returning access_token - Stack Overflow
