Getting access token in Blazor WASM Standalone
I have a Blazor WASM standalone app that uses Azure AD B2C for user and token management.
I've seen other questions/answers about this issue but in my case none of those approaches have worked and my Blazor WASM Standalone app is NOT able to get access tokens.
My Blazor app is set up as a SPA app on Azure AD B2C and it's important to note that "Access Tokens" and "Id Tokens" options are unchecked under "Implicit grant and hybrid flows" section. Also, "Allow public flows" is set to "No" -- see below. For these settings, I just followed the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-8.0#register-an-app-in-azure

I also added the "Read" and "Write" scopes for my API under "Configured Permissions" for my Blazor WASM app -- see below:

On the Blazor WASM side, this is what my Program.cs looks like:
...
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";
    //options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("openid");
    //options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("offline_access");
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("https://mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/api/MyApiUser.Write");
});

// Add HttpClient for My API calls
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("MyApiClient",
        client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.test.com"))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
    .CreateClient("MyApiClient"));

Please notice that I commented out the scopes for openid and offline_access but I did try it with them as well. Either way, it doesn't work and no access_token is received.
In this SO question/answer, the developer suggests using the Application Id for the Blazor WASM app instead of the scope URI worked for him. I did try the following and that did NOT work either. Here's that question: Blazor Standalone WASM Unable to get Access Token with MSAL
options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("cb3574c0-305e-4e44-a3b7-ac5f045f94e7"); // options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("https://mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/api/MyApiUser.Write");

Here the GUID value of cb3574c0-305e-4e44-a3b7-ac5f045f94e7 is the Application Id for my Blazor WASM app as assigned by Azure AD B2C.
When I inspect the HttpClient where I make my API calls, I see that DefaultRequestHeaders is null.
I don't believe Azure AD B2C is actually sending an access_token at all. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Can you attach the doc you are reffering for the code/project so that I can clone and try it

It's not a project but Microsoft docs. I just updated the original question with a link to that.

To resolve the error, pass scope as var scopes = new[] { "openid profile offline_access https://b2c.onmicrosoft.com/ClientID/ScopeName" }; and try

This reference is not blazor related but a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78600786/null-accesstoken-returned-from-authenticationresult/78676595#78676595

With a slight modification it WORKED!!! I just had to use open and close quotes for each scope i.e. var scopes = new[] { "openid", "profile", "offline_access" "https://mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/ClientID/ScopeName" }; THANK YOU!!!!

Maybe celebrated too soon. I'm now getting a weird error that reads "The provided application is not configured to allow public clients."

Make sure to mark the application as Public

And did you configure the redirect URL as SPA

By public, do you mean selecting "Yes" for "Allow public client flows"? The redirect URL is set correctly as https://localhost:7141/authentication/login-callback as "Single Page Application"

yes  select "Yes" for "Allow public client flows

It seems like it's hit and miss. It works first. I try again and I get that allow public clients error. I try again and it works again.

Try to restart the VS and try

OK. I tested it at least 6-7 times and it's working now. The "Allow public client flows" must be set to Yes. Please go ahead and post your answer. I really appreciate your help. I spent the whole day on this! THANK YOU!!!

Glad that I could help:)

Just accepted the answer. Thanks again. I really appreciate it!


Note that: Generating access token in Azure AD B2C depends on the scope you pass.


If you are passing invalid scope, access token will not be generated.

The error occurred as you are passing wrong scope https://mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/api/MyApiUser.Write
To resolve the error, make sure to pass scope as var scopes = new[] { "openid", "profile", "offline_access" "https://mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/ClientID/ScopeName" };
Modify the code by passing the valid scope:
...
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";
    //options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("openid");
    //options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("offline_access");
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("openid", "profile", "offline_access" "https://mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/ClientID/ScopeName"");
});

// Add HttpClient for My API calls
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("MyApiClient",
        client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.test.com"))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
    .CreateClient("MyApiClient"))

The error "The provided application is not configured to allow public clients." usually occurs if the Azure AD B2C application is not set as public.
To resolve the error, make sure to set Allow public client flows as YES:

Also make sure to configure redirect URL as SPA.
Reference:
c# - Null AccessToken returned from AuthenticationResult - Stack Overflow by me
